# Installation Error of android studio

Tags: android

this error occurs during the installation of android studio.
how to fix this error?
***The following SDK component was not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21***

Answer (score 1):

In windows

- First try to run as administrator if it doesn't work try following steps
- Download build-tools-21.1.1 from the following link: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21.1.1-windows.zip
- In windows, the android sdk will be will be located in: C:\Users\ \AppData\Android\sdk (AppData folder will be hidden by default, you can make it visible in "Folder Options")
- In this path - C:\Users\ \AppData\Android\sdk\build-tools, you'll already find a folder "21.1.2". In the same path, create a new folder and name it "21.1.1"
- Unzip the package that you downloaded in step (2). Copy the contents of the folder "android-5.0" and paste it in the folder "21.1.1" that you created in step (4). Run android studio.

Answer (score 0):

That is just an api that you wont need. It probobly has that error because your system doesnt support x86 files. Just my guess. Hope it helps.